# how to load rest api data in home page in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-getx

In home page/screen, i have 3 sections :

1. categories list view
2. popular food list view
3. new food list view

I want to load all api data whenever home page/screen load, i created methods for categories and popular food section.

But there is a problem only one funtion call in init method and one section is load but when i change any thing and save then next section load,

So what is the best way to call this api and load is UI properly.
here is my code.

Home Controller

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_admin/consts/consts.dart';
import '../api_service/api_endpoints.dart';
import '../model/category_model.dart';
import '../model/popular_recipe_model.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {


  var currentNavIndex = 0.obs;
  var isLoading = false.obs;

  //category list variable
  List categoryList = [].obs;

  //popular recipe list variable
  List popularRecipeList = [].obs;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchCategory();
    fetchPopularRecipe();
    super.onInit();
  }

  //change navigation tab index
  changeIndex(index) {
    currentNavIndex.value = index;
  }

// fetch category
  Future<List?> fetchCategory() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    isLoading.value = true;
    try {
      var response = await client.get(Uri.parse(
          ApiEndPoints.baseUrl + ApiEndPoints.authEndPoints.fetchCat));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonString = jsonDecode(response.body);
        var data = jsonString['data'];
        categoryList =
            List.from(data).map((e) => Categories.fromJson(e)).toList();
        isLoading.value = false;
        return categoryList;
      } else {
        Get.snackbar("Error", "data not found");
        return null;
      }
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
  }
 

//  fetch popular recipe
  Future<List?> fetchPopularRecipe() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    isLoading.value = true;
    try {
      var response = await client.get(Uri.parse(
          ApiEndPoints.baseUrl + ApiEndPoints.authEndPoints.popularRecipe));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonString = jsonDecode(response.body);
        var data = jsonString['data'];
        popularRecipeList =
            List.from(data).map((e) => PopularRecipe.fromJson(e)).toList();
        isLoading.value = false;
        return popularRecipeList;
      } else {
        Get.snackbar("Error", "data not found");
        return null;
      }
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
  }
}


Home Screen

   // ),
                Obx(()=>SizedBox(
                    height: Dimensions.height300,
                    child: controller.isLoading.value ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) : ListView.builder(
                        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: controller.popularRecipeList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return popularRecipe(
                              title: "${controller.popularRecipeList[index].name}",
                              time: "${controller.popularRecipeList[index].recipeTime}",
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.bookmark_outline_sharp),
                              img: "${controller.popularRecipeList[index].imageUrl}");
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because isLoading is set to false as soon as one of the Future completes. Use different flag for them or if you want to use a single flag then call a new Function in init method and wait in that function for the futures to complete.

```
Future<void> loadData() async {
    isLoading.value = true;
    await fetchCategory();
    await fetchPopularRecipe();
    isLoading.value = false;
}
```

Also, you don't need to return the value because you are already assigning in the function.